# Data will not draw onto my chart

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, chart.js

I am trying to output data onto a chart using the chart.js lib. I have successfully pulled the data out I need and created the datasets but for some reason it just will not render onto the chart.

I have three files:

teamData.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.ajax({
        url : "http://localhost/acredashAdv/teamData.php",
        type : "GET",
        success :function(data){
            console.log(data);

            var score_1 = [];
            var score_2 = [];

            for (var i in data) {
                 score_1.push(data[i].score_1);
                 score_2.push(data[i].score_2);
            }

            var chartata = {
                labels: [
                 "Strategic Development and Ownership", 
                 "Driving change through others", 
                 "Exec Disposition", 
                 "Commercial Acumen", 
                 "Develops High Performance Teams", 
                 "Innovation and risk taking", 
                 "Global Leadership", 
                 "Industry Leader"
                 ],

                datasets : [
                    {
                          label: "user 1",
                          backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0)",
                          borderColor: "#B71C1C",
                          data: score_1,
                    },
                    {
                          label: "user 2",
                          backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0)",
                          borderColor: "#B71C1C",
                          data: score_2
                    },                                                                                              

                ]
            };

            var ctx = $("#mycanvas");

            var LineGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'radar',
                data: chartata,
                animationEasing: 'linear'
            }); 
        },
        error :function(data){

        },
    });

});
```

teamData.php

```
<?php
include 'config.php';

$query = sprintf("SELECT member_id, firstName, lastName, score_1, score_2, score_3, score_4, score_5, score_6, score_7, score_8 FROM members");

$result = $conn->query($query);

$data = array();
foreach ($result as $row) {
  $data[] = $row;
}

$result->close();
$conn->close();

print json_encode($data);

?>
```

teams.php

```
<div style="max-width: 500px;">
  <canvas id="mycanvas" class="container"></canvas>
</div>
```

On my console.log I can see the data is coming through correctly:

```
[{"member_id":"144","firstName":"Dan","lastName":"Barrett","score_1":"4","score_2":"2","score_3":"3","score_4":"5","score_5":"1","score_6":"3","score_7":"5","score_8":"4"},{"member_id":"145","firstName":"Jon","lastName":"Smith","score_1":"3","score_2":"4","score_3":"1","score_4":"2","score_5":"1","score_6":"2","score_7":"3","score_8":"4"},{"member_id":"146","firstName":"Dan","lastName":"Barrett","score_1":"1","score_2":"2","score_3":"1","score_4":"1","score_5":"4","score_6":"1","score_7":"4","score_8":"3"}]
```

But unless I am getting mixed up it will not draw out the data... I end up with an empty chart.

[image]

Comment: Usually this things need the same amount of Data to plot and Labels, you have 8 labels and only 3 values in data (3 users in the console.log data)

Comment: hey man thanks for the reply, I did initially have the 8  set of data but to save space on here I cut it down but it just did the same thing. this is really tricky...

Comment: The odd thing is is, if I use say `member_id` or `score_1` as a label is produces loads of commas like `,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,`

Comment: try to put header('Content-type: application/json'); in the php, if not it returns text instead of a json

Comment: @PabloMartinez where is `header('Content-type: application/json');` going to go sorry?

Comment: @PabloMartinez ok so it seems to be outputting something now its all a bit off though...

Comment: After `include 'config.php'; ` in your php, for example xD

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133397/discussion-between-phpdude-and-pablo-martinez).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe could be the version of your Chart.js, here is your code running:

https://jsfiddle.net/6xdvj5u3/

Using this version of Chart.js

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.1.4/Chart.bundle.min.js

try to take the PabloMartinez's recommendation adding a header to your PHP file, before your print line:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
print json_encode($data);
```